# Changed gcm sender id in iOS plist, return error registering with GCM 401

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

Created two projects one for Android and another for iOS. Works total fine if using separated project number and api key. But my problem is that I want to use one pair project number and api key on my Server side, so if I change the sender id in iOS plist, it returns that the operation couldn't be completed with an error 401 when asking for a registration_id to GCM.
Anyone has ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code and whatever additional information is available on the server side to go with the returned 401.

Comment: the error message returns from google could messaging server, so we have no access to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm sounds like maybe you generated the sender ID from the wrong developer console.  It has to be a sender ID generated from the same project.